# Get Swasbuckle 5 to output Swagger 2.0 Json instead of OpenAPI 3.0

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi

I have upgraded my Swashbuckle to version 5 and everything is much better.

Now I have a problem that my consumers need the Swagger Json formattet as Swagger 2.0 instead of the default in Swashbuckle 5 that outputs the swagger in the Openapi 3.0.1 format.

My config is as follows:

```
    public static void ConfigureSwagger(SwaggerGenOptions c)
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "Gdpr Api",
            Version = "v1",
            Description ="This API is for GDPR ."
        });
        c.EnableAnnotations();
    }

    public static void ConfigureSwaggerUi(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "GDPR - Version 1");
            c.DocumentTitle = "Gdpr Swagger";
        });
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/#serialize-swagger-in-the-20-format

Answer (score 6):

I thought this was impossible until I found that you can do the following with the help of Helen and the [Release Notes for RC4](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/releases/tag/v5.0.0-rc4). The solution is to set `SerializeAsV2 = true`.

```
    public static void ConfigureSwaggerUi(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseSwagger(p => p.SerializeAsV2 = true);
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "GDPR - Version 1");
            c.DocumentTitle = "Gdpr Swagger";
        });
    }
```

This will output the Swagger JSON in the 2.0 format.